# How can I limit the number of decimal points in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, decimal-point

I have a UITextField that when clicked brings up a number pad with a decimal point in the bottom left. I am trying to limit the field so that a user can only place 1 decimal mark

e.g.
2.5 OK
2..5 NOT OK

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Implement the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method like this:

```
// Only allow one decimal point
// Example assumes ARC - Implement proper memory management if not using.
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray  *arrayOfString = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([arrayOfString count] > 2 ) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

This creates an array of strings split by the decimal point, so if there is more than one decimal point we will have at least 3 elements in the array.

Comment: Rather than using componentsSeparatedByString, you could use a NSRegularExpression to determine whether the newString contains more than one decimal.

Comment: True!  There are lots of ways to do this.  I generally use this because often I want to do something different with the integer and decimal portion.

Comment: Using a regular expression gives you better control of the characters the textfield accept and the format they will take.

Comment: @nizx For this specific case I don't think that it really matters much, although your example is longer and "looks" more complicated to a new user.  For more complicated examples, you may very well be right, or if they are numbers then using a NSNumberFormatter may also be appropriate.

Comment: Instead of @"." for the decimal separator one could also get it from [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]]. This way the code will also work correctly for regions using a comma as separator.

Comment: @Frank Very true, however the question specifically asked about "decimal points" and I don't want to cloud the issue.  :)

Comment: @Inafziger In the Netherlands the keypad will show a comma on the decimal pad, not a dot. Hence using a hardcoded '.' would not give the wanted/expected results

Comment: @Frank Oh, I get that and it's a very valid point (and in fact what I do) but this question was specifically about a decimal point, and not the decimal seperator. :)

Comment: Also, by adding another condition to the 'if' statement, making it ` if ([arrayOfString count] > 2 || ([arrayOfString count] == 2 && [arrayOfString.lastObject length] > 2))
` one could limit the number of chars after the decimal point as well (in this case **no more than 2** characters allowed)

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example with a regular expression, the example limits to only one decimal point and 2 decimals. You can tweak it to fit your needs.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    return numberOfMatches != 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. As a constructive critic, I'll recommend you to improve your RegEx knowledge. Things like "([0-9]+)?" can be replaced by "[0-9]*" It makes it more readable and also more performant. I already did the proper improvements to the answer.

Comment: @"^-?[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$" for ability to enter negative numbers too.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3** Implement this UITextFieldDelegate method to prevent user from typing an invalid number:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let text = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]*)?$", options: .caseInsensitive) {
        return regex.numberOfMatches(in: newText, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newText as NSString).length)) > 0
    }
    return false
}
```

It is working with both comma or dot as decimal separator. You can also limit number of fraction digits using this pattern: `"^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$"` (in this case 2).

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 4

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Allow to remove character (Backspace)
    if string == "" {
        return true
    }

   // Block multiple dot
    if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
        return false
    }

    // Check here decimal places
    if (textField.text?.contains("."))! {
        let limitDecimalPlace = 2
        let decimalPlace = textField.text?.components(separatedBy: ".").last
        if (decimalPlace?.count)! < limitDecimalPlace {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

## Objective-C

```
//Create this variable in .h file or .m file
float _numberOfDecimal;

//assign value in viewDidLoad method
numberOfDecimal = 2;

#pragma mark - TextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Allow to remove character (Backspace)
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return true;
    }

    // Block multiple dot
    if ([textField.text containsString:@"."] && [string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check here decimal places
    if ([textField.text containsString:@"."]) {
        NSString *strDecimalPlace = [[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];

        if (strDecimalPlace.length < _numberOfDecimal) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 2.3 to prevent user for enter decimal number after two places -**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let decimalPlacesLimit = 2
    let rangeDot = txtPrice.text!.rangeOfString(".", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)

    if rangeDot?.count > 0
    {
        if (string == ".")
        {
            print("textField already contains a separator")
            return false
        }
        else {

            var explodedString = txtPrice.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
            let decimalPart = explodedString[1]
            if decimalPart.characters.count >= decimalPlacesLimit && !(string == "")
            {
                print("textField already contains \(decimalPlacesLimit) decimal places")
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the accepted answer, the following approach validates three cases that are helpful when dealing with money formats:

1. Extremely large amounts
2. More than 2 characters after the decimal point
3. More than 1 decimal points

Make sure your text field's delegate is set properly, your class conforms to the `UITextField` protocol, and add the following delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  // Check for deletion of the $ sign
  if (range.location == 0 && [textField.text hasPrefix:@"$"])
    return NO;

  NSString *updatedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  NSArray *stringsArray = [updatedText componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

  // Check for an absurdly large amount
  if (stringsArray.count > 0)
  {
    NSString *dollarAmount = stringsArray[0];
    if (dollarAmount.length > 6)
      return NO;
  }

  // Check for more than 2 chars after the decimal point
  if (stringsArray.count > 1)
  {
    NSString *centAmount = stringsArray[1];
    if (centAmount.length > 2)
      return NO;
  }

  // Check for a second decimal point
  if (stringsArray.count > 2)
    return NO;

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is a case not correctly handled: if you have reached 6 characters in the dollarAmount, you may want to enter centAmount anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    if(textField == min_textfield )
    {
        if([textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            if([string isEqualToString:@"."] )
            {
                flag_for_text = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                textField.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if([string isEqualToString:@"."])
            {
                return NO;
            }
            else 
            {
                textField.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
public func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if(text == "," || text == "." ){
        let countdots = textView.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1

        if countdots > 0 && (text == "." || text == "," )
        {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: `text` can be multiple characters so you can't check it like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

No need to create an array and check count. Limit user can only place 1 decimal mark like this.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string.contains(".")
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

max number of Integers Numbers is 4 i.e., 9999, and max decimal digits limit is 2. So, max number can be 9999.99

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    // 100 is the tag value of our textfield
    /*or you may use "if textfield == myTextField{" if you have an IBOutlet to that textfield */
    if textField.tag == 100 {

        //max length limit of text is 8
        if textField.text!.count > 8 && string != "" {
            return false
        }

        let maxLength = 8
        let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
```

// Use following code If you are inputting price to that text field and want $ to get inserted automatically at start when user starts typing in that textfield or you may put some other character at start instead of $. Otherwise comment the following 3 lines of if condition code

```
        if currentString.length == 0 {
            priceTextField.text = "$"
        }
```

//new string after inserting the new entered characters

```
        let newString: NSString =
            currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString


        if newString.length > maxLength{
            return false
        }

        if (textField.text!.range(of: ".") != nil) {
            let numStr = newString.components(separatedBy: ".")
            if numStr.count>1{
                let decStr = numStr[1]
                if decStr.length > 2{
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        var priceStr: String = newString as String

        if (textField.text!.range(of: "$") != nil) {
            priceStr = priceStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
        }

        let price: Double = Double(priceStr) ?? 0

        if price > 9999.99{
            return false
        }

        switch string {
        case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
            return true
        case ".":
            let array = Array(textField.text!)
            var decimalCount = 0
            for character in array {
                if character == "." {
                    decimalCount = decimalCount + 1
                }
            }

            if decimalCount == 1 {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        default:

            let array = Array(string)
            if array.count == 0 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **SWIFT 5**

**Improvement**

Info : do not allow :

- separator at the beginning
- zero plus another digit at the start except when you add a separator after

**1: set the keyboard type to : Decimal Pad**

[image]

**2: copy past**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //!\ set the keyboard type to : Decimal Pad /!\\
    // CUSTOM SETUP
    let c = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
    let limitBeforeSeparator = 2
    let limitAfterSeparator = 2
    // ---------
    
    
    var validatorUserInput:Bool = false
    
    let text = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    
    
    // Validator
    let pattern = "(?!0[0-9])\\d*(?!\\\(c))^[0-9]{0,\(limitBeforeSeparator)}((\\\(c))[0-9]{0,\(limitAfterSeparator)})?$"
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive) {
        validatorUserInput = regex.numberOfMatches(in: newText, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newText as NSString).length)) > 0
    }
     
    
    if validatorUserInput {
        // setting data or something eles before the return
        if let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            if (isBackSpace == -92 && textField.text?.count == 1) {
                print("Backspace was pressed")
                print(newText)
                // do something...
                
            } else {
                print("Number Added")
                print(newText)
                // do something...
                
            }
        }
        return validatorUserInput
    } else {
        return validatorUserInput
    }
}
```

**3: set in the method, if you want x maximum number of digits before and after the separator**

```
 let limitBeforeSeparator = 2 
 let limitAfterSeparator = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In whatever object you set your UITextField's delegate to, add a method that answers to ["`[- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string]`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412491/realtime-formatting-with-nsnumberformatter-in-a-uitextfield).

Then you can either use a `NSNumberFormatter` object or you can brute force check for an already existing decimal place mark (returning `NO` if a decimal mark already exists).

Answer (score 0):

Short told, the number format is as follows `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%9.5f", x];` Where 5 is the decimal after ",".

Answer (score 0):

I made the solution, that brings you control over decimal places count, so user can type only one decimal separator and you can also have a control over decimal places count.

Just set the **decimalPlacesLimit** value properly.

See the method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"text on the way: %@", string);
    NSUInteger decimalPlacesLimit = 2;

    NSRange rangeDot = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange rangeComma = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"," options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (rangeDot.length > 0 || rangeComma.length > 0){
        if([string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains a separator");
            return NO;
        } else {
            NSArray *explodedString = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];
            if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSLog(@"textField already contains %d decimal places", decimalPlacesLimit);
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

The efficient and easy way to avoid multiple decimal points (. or ,) in UITextField:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if(string == "," || string == "." ){

        if ((textField.text?.contains(","))! || (textField.text?.contains("."))!){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if([string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        BOOL containsDecimal = [textField.text containsString:@"."];
        return !containsDecimal;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If textfield text already contains a '.' then return NO else return YES.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks everyone, I needed to limit the number before and after the dot. It was only with a regular expression that this became possible for me.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if string == "," {
        textField.text = textField.text! + "."
        return false
    }
    
    
    guard let newTextField = textField.text else { return false }
    if !string.isEmpty {
        let text = newTextField as NSString
        let newText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]{0,4}$*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,4})?$", options: .caseInsensitive) {
            return regex.numberOfMatches(in: newText, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newText as NSString).length)) > 0
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
    
    //        @"^[0-9]{0,3}$*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$"
    
}
```